# Combining scale_shape(solid = TRUE) and scale_shape(solid = FALSE) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm drawing a figure in ggplot2 that shows individual participant values and group means. I want to show the individual values using non-filled points, and means using filled points, grouped by colour.

As an example using sample data:

```
 group <- c("high", "high", "high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "low", "low", "low")
 condition <- c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c2")
 value <- c(.91, .63, .5, NA, NA, NA, .93, .76, .43, .5, .6, .8)
 subj <- c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6")

 sample.data <- data.frame(group, condition, value, subj)


 ggplot(sample.data, aes(x=condition, y=value)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape = group), size = 2, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(2,1)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group=subj), colour='lightgrey') +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point", aes(shape=group, fill = group),
       size=5, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(group=group, colour=group), geom='line', 
       size=.8, position = position_dodge(.1))
```

[image: example figure]

In the code I specify that I want the fill to be determined by group, but this doesn't work, as shown in the figure. I've also tried adding `scale_shape(solid=FALSE)` as in:

```
 ggplot(sample.data, aes(x=condition, y=value)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape = group), size = 2, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
    scale_shape(solid = FALSE) +
    geom_line(aes(group=subj), colour='lightgrey') +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point", aes(shape=group, fill = group),
       size=5, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(group=group, colour=group), geom='line', 
       size=.8, position = position_dodge(.1))
```

But that generates the exact same figure.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, you did that. Do you want different `scale_shape` values for your `stat_summary` lines vs your `geom_point`s? Can you specify which points should be filled in and which should be hollow?

Comment: The shapes you gave, shapes 1 & 2, are just outlines. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-plot-pch-symbols-the-different-point-shapes-available-in-r The equivalent outlined and filled shapes would be 21 & 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you probably just want to refer to the filled shapes, which have their own values, so its a simple change to your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sample.data, aes(x=condition, y=value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=group, shape=group), size = 2, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=subj), colour='lightgrey') +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point", aes(shape=group, fill = group),
               size=5, position = position_dodge(.1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(group=group, colour=group), geom='line', 
               size=.8, position = position_dodge(.1)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(24,21))
```

[image: filled shapes]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!